# Can I combine Haste, Green Flame Blade, Divine Smite, and Thunderous Smite like this?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions

This question is asking if my coup de grace manoeuvre action-sequence, that could only be pulled off once per long rest, is working as intended. I'll try to keep what I am trying to do as simple as possible.

In this scenario, I am a level 5 sorcerer and level 2 paladin.

Round one; cast *haste* on self.

Round two; try to hit target with longsword casting *green flame blade*, and expending a level 3 spell slot for *divine smite*, then follow up with a second attack using my 2nd lvl 3 level spell slot for a 2nd *divine smite*, but with my bonus action stop concentrating on *haste*, and cast *thunderous smite* as a bonus action, landing the hit for a total of:
1d8+2+4d8+1d6+1d8+2+4d8+2d6.

For the sake of this question, let's assume I have all of my spell slots unused.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Round 1 - Cast Haste** - no issue, here. Though you could squeeze in one more attack (possible Divine Smite-ed) after casting.

**Round 2.1 - Cast Green Flame Blade, on a hit, use Divine Smite** - Divine Smite only needs you to hit with a melee weapon attack, which GFB does. No problem.

**Round 2.2 - Hasted attack with Divine Smite** - Pretty standard.

**Round 2.3 - Cast Thunderous Smite and hit** - Nope! You can only *cast* Thunderous Smite, but you can't attack anymore- having expended all your attacks. You already attacked with your Hasted attack. You can't Two-weapon fight either, because Thunderous Smite is a Bonus Action.

TL;DR- Everything is legal, but you can't attack after using Thunderous Smite.

Answer (score 11):

## No, this is not possible.

On round two, you don't need to use a bonus action to stop concentrating on *haste*, because dropping concentration is free. If you *did* stop concentrating on *haste*, you will lose this current turn and feel lethargic, unable to take the rest of your turn *and* your next turn per the spell description.

This means when you cast *thunderous smite*, you will be unable to take your actions to attack/cast spells. *Thunderous smite* only works as a buff, it doesn't let you also attack with the casting, so to use *Thunderous smite*, you would have to cast it before GFB/your 2nd attack.

Answer (score 3):

### Long Story Short: Not as such

**Round 1**: You cast *haste*. So far, so good, though I would then recommend using the extra action provided to make a weapon attack, boosted by Divine Smite if you wish.

**Round 2a**: Cast *green-flame blade*, using your Divine Smite for extra damage. So far, so good.

**Round 2b**: Extra attack from *haste*, Divine Smite for extra damage. Still working out fine.

**Round 2c**: Drop *haste* concentration to cast *thunderous smite* and attack. No can do. After dropping concentration on *haste*, the formerly hasted creature cannot move or take actions until *after* its next turn. While you can cast *thunderous smite* using a bonus action, you cannot make further attacks this turn, having consumed your extra hasted action, nor can you attack next round, due to the fallout from dropping haste. What this also means is that you cannot drop concentration in the middle and then cast/attack with *thunderous smite*, as the lack of actions start as soon as *haste* wears off.

**Round 3**: Can't do anything of note due to the *haste* fallout, though you may maintain concentration on *thunderous smite* should you choose.

**Round 4**: You can finally make an attack to release that *thunderous smite* you've been holding onto.

**Tl;dr**: Just keep *haste* up and either multi-attack or *green-flame blade* and *haste* attack each turn, it'll do more total damage. And it will also avoid wasting a 3rd level slot on what ends up being a 1-turn thing.

Answer (score 1):

This would not work because the Haste spell when dropped leaves you temporarily exhausted until the end of your next round.

Now if you did the reverse:

1. Round one: TS -> GFB + DS
2. Round two: Haste, regular hit hasted action then Quickened Spell GFB

That would work.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Your "round 2" example is incorrect as currently written; if you cast any spell as a bonus action, the only other spell you can cast that turn is a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action. You could, however, quicken *haste* and then cast *green-flame blade* with your regular action.